# How to insert multiple rows record in multiple columns of single row in datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

When I query the table "class_attendance".

```
select rollno, name, fname, date, attandance from class_attendance where class = '6th' and month = 'November'
```

I get this.

```
rollno    name         fname        date        attandance    
111      zeeshan        Khan      2013-11-08        P
111      zeeshan        Khan      2013-11-09        P
111      zeeshan        Khan      2013-11-28        A
112      ahmad          Ali       2013-11-28        P
```

And I want to show it in datagridview like this (Date wise).

```
rollno     name         fname       8     9     28
111      zeeshan        Khan        P     P      A
112      ahmad          Ali                      P
```

Ho should i do this?

Comment: So how could i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
select rollno,name,fname,[8],[9],[28]
FROM 
(
    select rollno,name,fname, DATEPART(d,[date]) enterdate,attandance 
    from students
)first
PIVOT
(
  MAX(attandance)
  FOR [enterdate]
  IN ([8],[9],[28])
)
as pivottable
```

This is giving me following output:-

[image]

You can then display this data in your gridview.

Comment: but what about the whole month?

Comment: @Loyal - Then obviously `SQL Pivot` is not a good option! You didn't mentioned that in your question. For a whole month, don't you think your grid will be too large?

Comment: yeah it will be large but actually i want to display the whole month attendance record of the specific class.

Comment: Can we do it programatically?

Comment: @Loyal - Lets discuss this over chat!

Comment: @Loyal - If you'll hardcode the values from 1-30 instead of (8,9,28) what i have used, you will get your desired output, But thats a `good` way.

Comment: @ Rahul how to chat over stackoverflow, i don't know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65433/discussion-between-loyal-and-rahul-singh).